# Build.PL wont run in git repo

Tags: perl, bioperl

I am trying to run the bioperl-live package and I have git-cloned the following repo

```
git clone https://github.com/bioperl/bioperl-live.git
```

and cd'd into bio-perl live where it was installed. I have then tried to run:

```
perl Build.PL
```

to which I get back:

```
Checking prerequisites...
  build_requires:
    !  Test::Most is not installed
```

so I have opened up a cpan shell and when i run from cpan:

```
cpan>install Test::Most
```

and repeat the build I get the same error. Would anyone mind cloning the above git repo ( found at https://github.com/bioperl/bioperl-live if you want to check yourself) and let me know if you are encountering the same problem.

note this doesn't happen for other Build.PL files in other packages - it runs fine. there must be something in that git repo that's corrupt/missing.

Thanks

update - when I run perl -wle 'use Test::Most'

I get:

Can't locate Test/Most.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/arron/src/bioperl-live /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.12.4 /usr/local/share/perl/5.12.4 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.12 /usr/share/perl/5.12 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.`enter code here`

Also configuring cpan to install as root and then installing Test::Most makes no difference. such a fuss!

Comment: `perl Build.PL \n Can't locate Bio/Root/Build.pm in @INC...` I guess I need bioperl to use this?

Comment: Ahh, I see, there's a separate and undocumented Bio-Root repository. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is a problem with bioperl.  More likely the `cpan` command you're using is not installing for the `perl` you're using to run the `Build.PL`.  So Test::Most is getting installed but not for your perl.  You can confirm if Test::Most is installed with `perl -wle 'use Test::Most'`.

Check `which cpan` and `which perl`.  They should have the same root path.  ie. `/usr/bin/cpan` and `/usr/bin/perl`.

One possibility is you're running `sudo cpan` but just `perl Build.PL`.  `sudo` may be changing your `PATH` and thus picking up a different `cpan` and a different `perl`.  If you are doing `sudo cpan` be sure to do `sudo which cpan`.

You can check which perl cpan is installing to by typing `! print "$^X\n"` at a cpan prompt.  `!` tells cpan to execute arbitrary perl code.  `$^X` is a variable which holds the path to perl.  Here's an example where cpan is installing for the correct perl.

```
$ cpan

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9800)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> ! print "$^X\n"
/Users/schwern/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.2-threads/bin/perl
cpan[1]> q

$ which perl
/Users/schwern/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.2-threads/bin/perl
```

Also you should avoid running cpan as root and instead [configure CPAN to install as root](http://www.preshweb.co.uk/2011/03/configuring-cpan-pm-to-use-sudo-to-install/).  You may need to `sudo chown yourusername -R ~/.cpan` in order for this to work because root probably owns your `.cpan` directory.

Comment: sorry, what difference between `perl -wle 'use Test::Most'` and `perl -e 'use Test::Most'`? I never used this options before. Always use onle `-e` option

Comment: `-w` turns on warnings. `-l` sets `$\ ` to a newline, which makes `print` add a newline.

Comment: @Schwern - please see my updated question to see the results of running perl -wle 'use Test::Most'

Comment: @Suic `-wle` is my habit for command line programs, there's little reason to not use `-wl` so I always do. `-e` will work just as well.

Comment: @brucezepplin Based on what you wrote, it is definitely not a bioperl issue. The cpan you're invoking is not installing to the perl you're using. It's for some other perl installed on the machine. Post the output of the various `which` commands and we can sort it out. You can also determine which perl the CPAN shell is using with `! print "$^X\n"` at the `cpan>` prompt.